# Spring Transaction, Hibernate, and INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint

Tags: java, sql, spring, hibernate

I am wondering why my code gives me `The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_tbl_bo_gui_group_user_tbl_bo_gui_user". The conflict occurred in database "IVRBODBDEV", table "dbo.tbl_bo_gui_user", column 'id'.`.

I've put the `@Transactional` annotation because another DAO is taking care of the record inserts for the junction table.

```
@Override
@Transactional
public void addUser(User user, String[] group, String createdBy) throws Exception {
    String userId = getUserDao().addUser(user, createdBy);

    getGroupUserDao().addGroupUser(userId, group, createdBy);
}
```

The `addUser` in `UserDaoImpl` class:

```
@Override
public String addUser(User user, String createdBy) throws Exception {
    try {
        log.info("Adding user...");

        user.setDateCreated(DateUtil.getDateTime());
        user.setCreatedBy(createdBy);

        getCurrentSession().save(user);

        return user.getId();
    } catch(Exception e) {
        log.error("Adding user failed. MESSAGE: " + e.getMessage());
        throw e;
    }
}
```

Comment: Use hibernate correctly. You are basically using hibernate in a way you would use plain JDBC. Get your mappings right and you should then only have to save the user (and groups and junctions will be filled by hibernate).

Comment: @M.Deinum Is there a way to reference an uncommitted ID to another table?

Comment: No, not if there is a FOREIGN_KEY constraint. As mentioned you should be using hibernate properly instead of adding/updating yourself let hibernate do that for you.

Comment: @M.Deinum How can hibernate insert a `uniqueidentifier` to the junction table if I do the relationships mapping? The PKs that are `uniqueidentifier` in type is given by my application, not by the database.

Comment: Generate the `uniqueIdentifier`s first then let hibernate do the remainder or implement your own `IdentifierGenerator` to integrate it with hibernate.